# using jQuery animate() for lettering.js plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

On its [documentation](https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js/) to manipulate each letter it is mentioned to use CSS and I am trying to target a specific letter with jQuery `animate()` function unfortunately don't see what I am expecting. Is it possible to use jQuery in this case ?

Default `script`

```
<h1 class="fancy_title">AWESOME</h1>

 <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".fancy_title").lettering();
     });
</script>
```

What I am trying ...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.char1').hide(1000).show(1000)
    .animate({left: '400', opacity: 0.5}, 3000)
    .animate({left: '-400', opacity: 1}, 300); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all your JS code into document redy like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fancy_title").lettering();
    $('.char1').hide(1000).show(1000)
    .animate({left: '400', opacity: 0.5}, 3000)
    .animate({left: '-400', opacity: 1}, 300); 
});
```

Remove this section:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".fancy_title").lettering();
     });
</script>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xcpmoadt/4/)

Check that you include the script "lettering.js" in your html

Comment: I see it working now and I see you added a script into actual plugin js ... can you tell me why it is not working in a separate js ?

Comment: I think the problem is in way where you including the "lettering.js". Check if you including this file before your scripts

Comment: you are right. I put my js file after plugin.js and its script now it works fine. Thank you !